# iOS getting the crash while displaying Facebook video ads

Tags: ios, facebook, crash, facebook-audience-network

Crash log is here:-

We are simply getting the ads from Facebook Audience Network and showing in list view.

We are using FBMedia view from XIB as demonstrated by Facebook Audience Network sample app. Somehow the AVplayer getting deallocated before removing observer.

Can someone please help on this.

```
2016-07-19 16:22:02.905 NewsHunt[59124:1425162] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An instance of AVPlayer cannot remove a time observer that was added by a different instance of AVPlayer.'
```

*** First throw call stack:

(

0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bd55d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b7c9deb objc_exception_throw + 48

2   AVFoundation                        0x0000000106c25ee7 -[AVPlayer _removeAllLayers] + 0

3   NewsHunt                            0x0000000105c2d721 -[FBAdVideoView removeAllTimingObservers] + 369

4   NewsHunt                            0x0000000105c2b167 -[FBAdVideoView playMovieWithURL:withVideoPlayCheck:withVideoTimeCheck:withFailure:] + 183

5   NewsHunt                            0x0000000105c5b8df -[FBMediaView loadVideo] + 671

6   NewsHunt                            0x0000000105c5b045 -[FBMediaView loadNativeAd:] + 389

7   NewsHunt                            0x0000000105c5ae8f -[FBMediaView setNativeAd:] + 431

8   NewsHunt                            0x00000001056c0180 -[DHFANAdCommunicator renderAdOnView:andParentViewController:] + 240

9   NewsHunt                            0x00000001055e1f8c -[DHMultipleExternalAdResponse renderAdOnView:andParentViewController:] + 124

10  NewsHunt                            0x00000001056c3baf -[DHCardP1AdRenderer setAd:onView:] + 143

11  NewsHunt                            0x0000000105850113 -[NewsListViewController tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:] + 467

12  UIKit                               0x00000001095ba59c -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 934

13  UIKit                               0x00000001095ba62c -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74

14  UIKit                               0x000000010958ed4f -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2996

15  UIKit                               0x00000001095c3686 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 92

16  UIKit                               0x00000001095aa344 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 224

17  UIKit                               0x0000000109517980 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703

18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108f8cc00 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146

19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108f8108e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366

20  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108f80f0c _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24

21  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108f753c9 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277

22  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108fa3086 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486

23  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108fb1b5c _ZN2CA7Display11DisplayLink14dispatch_itemsEyyy + 576

24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bcaf074 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 20

25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bcaec21 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1089

26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bc70b11 __CFRunLoopRun + 1937

27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bc700f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488

28  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010df72ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161

29  UIKit                               0x000000010945cf09 UIApplicationMain + 171

30  NewsHunt                            0x0000000105763767 main + 151

31  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010cfeb92d start + 1

32  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1

)

Comment: I've found that FAN crashes on any iOS 8 device.